# CodeIgniter: Submit form with button link

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to the codeigniter.
I have signup form with 3 textfield and 1 dropdown. Sign up button is a link button and it is designed with CSS3.

```
<p><a class="button-link" href="#">Create Account</a></p>
```

Added the `form` helper class in `autoload.php` and loaded it in the controller method with
 `$this->load->helper(‘form’);`
I have gone through few codeigniter tutorials but in those tutorial all the fields and Submit button were created with form api it self. It was like

```
echo form_input('first_name', set_value('first_name', 'First Name'));
echo form_input('last_name', set_value('last_name', 'Last Name'));
echo form_input('email_address', set_value('email_address', 'Email Address'));
echo form_submit('submit', 'Create Acccount');
```

But my form has all the html fields. Here are my issues:

- how to set html form input field values.
- how to submit form from a link button.
- Want to do javascript validation submitting the form.

  Note: I don't want to make an ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the form data to a controller with index to validate form and another function to check the database.

```
   <?php echo form_open('controllername'); ?>
     <label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
     <br/>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
   </form>
```

Check this [link](http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html)